# EC2 instance: non ec2-user not in sudoer file?

Tags: amazon-ec2, sudo

Amazon EC2-instance:
I made a user 'admin' and copied ec2-user's keys with proper permission.
After successful login, i tried to do sudo su for root access, it says 'admin is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.'

However i can do sudo su with ec2-user account and can gain root access.

What is sudoer file? how does ec2-user and admin different in config wise?

```
# useradd -m admin
# cp -R /home/ec2-user/.ssh /home/admin
# chown -R admin:admin /home/admin/.ssh
```

connect by putty:
login as: admin
Authenticating with public key "xxx"
    [admin@ip-xx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ sudo su

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:
1) Respect the privacy of others.
2) Think before you type.
3) With great power comes great responsibility.

```
[sudo] password for admin:
admin is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your sudoers filer and enable your admin user. You should only edit your sudoers file with the `visudo` command as this checks the syntax etc. Something like

```
admin    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

will do. This allows your admin user to execute any command as on any host as any user after supplying a password.

Check the [sudoers](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.3/sudoers.man.html) and [sudo](http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/man/1.8.3/sudo.man.html) man pages

Answer (score 3):

I got a **Simple Solution**:

1. login as root user
2. create a user `useradd user1`
3. create a password for a user `passwd user1`
4. if you are using amazon ec2 linux add your user to wheel group by `usermod -aG wheel user1`
5. then, try to login as your user `su user1`
6. use any root command now `sudo less /etc/shadow`
7. it Prompt for a password now enter it..

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new user using 'useradd user1'
2. Set password for the user 'passwd user1'
3. Add user to the group wheel 'gpasswd -a user1 wheel'
4. Logged in as ec2-user open visudo using 'sudo visudo'
5. Uncomment the line starting with %wheel. i.e. remove the # before 
    %wheel ALL=(ALL)       ALL
6. Logout
7. Login back as ec2-user
8. Switch to the user created 'su - user1'
9. Execute any command with sudo flag to run as root

Worked for me